# "tail -f" makes disk full?

Tags: logging, disk, tail, sunos

our application server (sunOS) always gets disk full. and our Infrastructure team said it's caused by too many "tail -f" processes. Because the app rotates log file frequently, it caused the dead link and no disk space?
I've never heard of this before. does that command really cause disk full?

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for one of Stack Overflow's sister sites, http://www.serverfault.com.

Comment: thank you, Adam. Let me post it to serverfault.com . btw, I see the tail process will be killed after we exit the putty session or press 'Ctrl+C', why there are so many tail processes reading log files?

Comment: that is an _excellent_ question. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Linux sysadminning to tell you how to track that down. Good luck with ServerFault's version of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space a file occupies cannot be reclaimed until all references to that file are gone. Therefore, any process that has the file open will prevent the file from being deleted from the disk.

An active `tail -f` following the file, for example.

If these files *need* to be deleted to free disk space (e.g. because they are very big, or there are very many of them), then having processes lying around that hold references to them will prevent their deletion, and eventually lead to the disk filling up.

Edit in response to the comment on the other answer:

The diagnostics you report are *exactly* what you would expect to see in the situation that Adam and I describe. `df` reports that `56G` of disk are in use, and `du` reports that only `10G` are visible in the folder. The discrepancy is because there are `46G` worth of files that have been removed from the folder, but cannot be physically removed from disk because some processes are holding a references to them.

It's easy enough to experiment with this yourself: find a filesystem it's safe to play with, and create a humongous file. Write a C program that opens the file and goes into an infinite loop. Now, do the following:

- Start the program
- Check the output of `df`
- `rm` the file
- Check the output of `df` again
- Stop your program
- Check the output of `df` again

You will see that the output of `df` doesn't change after `rm`ing the file, but does change once you stop the program (thus removing the last reference to the file).

If you need even more evidence that this is what's going on, you may be able to get information from the `/proc` filesystem, if you have it. Specifically, find the PID of one of the `tail -f` processes (or other processes you think might be the cause), and look at the directory `/proc/<pid>/fd` to see all of the files it has open.

(I don't have *nix at home, so I can't actually check to see just what you'll see `/proc/<pid>/fd` in this situation)

Comment: thanks very much, Hurkyl. Yes, I finally find out the root cause. my application did not kill all called remote processes when it exits.

Answer (score 0):

`tail` is a command to view the end of a file, and `-f` performs that in real-time, updating the display whenever the file itself is modified. It allows real-time views of log files.

`tail` can cause problems in two ways:

1. If `tail -f` is being misused to write to a file instead of an interactive console, it is an inefficient means of copying a file, and it's creating duplicate logs.
2. `tail -f` keeps the log file alive, so maintenance tasks trying to automatically delete log files fail. This throws off the log file rotation by not allowing the old one to age off.

If your infrastructure team is complaining about access to files less than a week old, you *really* need more drive space and/or a less-verbose logging strategy, since they can't keep enough logs alive in case something goes wrong and needs to be tracked. If the logs are older than that, they may have a good point, and excessive usage of `tail`- like anything else keeping the file open- may be preventing it from being deleted in a timely manner.

The command on its own is unlikely to be filling the disk, but it may be preventing disk hygiene operations.

Comment: Adam, 
when i typed the command, "df -h", and gets below
/dev/md/dsk/d1          59G    56G   2.5G    96%    /log

but, if i go to the log directory, typed "du -sh", it looks the size of that foler is not as big as shown above
:/log> du -sh
  10G   .
  
and we find there are many "tail -f" processes, may be dead, reading the log file in that folder. thus we doubt that those tail processes use up the space